# Linux Bash - Write to log - No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, append, cat, logfile

I would want to append a line to a logfile but I keep getting "No such file or directory"

```
cat "$NOW : Version $VERSION already installed on HOSTNAME!" >> /var/log/dig-nscp-install.log
```

I'm 100 % sure the file exists and it is writable when I nano it.

When i try it in cli,

```
cat 'Hellooo test'>>/var/log/dig-nscp-install.log
```

I also get `cat: Hellooo test: No such file or directory`

Any help / tips what I might be doing wrong?

thanks.

Comment: It seems that you need `echo` instead of `cat`.

Answer (score 3):

`cat` outputs the content of a file. You should be using `echo`, which just echoes a string to stdout:

```
echo "$NOW : Version $VERSION already installed on HOSTNAME!" >> /var/log/dig-nscp-install.log
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `echo` instead of `cat`

do this

```
echo "$NOW : Version $VERSION already installed on HOSTNAME!" >> /var/log/dig-nscp-install.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The error `No such file or directory` is about a hypothetical file named `$NOW : Version $VERSION already installed on HOSTNAME!`, not about `/var/log/dig-nscp-install.log`. As others have mentioned, use `echo` rather than `cat` as `cat` expects a file descriptor (e.g. a filename.)

```
echo "$NOW : Version $VERSION already installed on HOSTNAME!" >> /var/log/dig-nscp-install.log
```